# How to change the order of languages in Region & language settings?

Tags: windows-10, language, regional-settings

In the 'Region & language' settings (Language settings), I can easily add a language.  How can I control the order of this list?

The settings on the tab clearly states:

> Apps and websites will appear in the first language in the list that
>   they support.

I am not able to find any instructions on setting the order.  The reason behind this is I need to do testing of an app and I want to control what language comes first as our app supports multiple languages.  So in the example below I would like to put Thai first, followed by English (United Kingdom).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on one of the entries, several buttons will appear:

[image: selecting one produces up, down, Options, and Remove buttons]

Click on the up or down arrow to change the selected language's position.

If you need to automate the change, you can use PowerShell! The [`Get-WinUserLanguageList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/get-winuserlanguagelist?view=win10-ps) cmdlet retrieves the current arrangement of languages. You can swap the items around and save your changes by passing the adjusted list to [`Set-WinUserLanguageList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuserlanguagelist?view=win10-ps).